# iPad Mail app doesn't completely search inbox or contact

Tags: ipad, mail.app, email

I tried to use my Mail app connected to Hotmail and Gmail to search for emails in my inbox and contacts, but the app doesn't fully search my emails in the inbox nor the contacts I have saved. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: iPad search sometimes seems limited. Does it give you an option to "continue search on server"? What about going out into the specific account's "All Mail" folder, or inbox to search there?

Comment: @bassplayer7 ive done "continue search on server" the email still doesn't come out

Comment: User133466, if you tried all the search criteria combination and it still doesn't show up then its probably no use. I had that experience many times and had to go back to my desktop and find the email.

Answer (score -1):

Same experience. The only way I found was to go back to the good old desktop.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: I don't have a question. I am merely suggesting a workaround.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks. I appreciate that. I guess my answer is: there isn't much user133466 can do. It's broken. I also had that problem for a very long time and the only way I found is to not search on the phone but on the computer. What I want (and presumably user144366 as well) is to find his old email so until google and yahoo and/or apple all fix their mobile mail app search, this is only way I have found. Sorry can't be more helpful than that.